# Excluding Descriptive Info from Ordination, while keeping it associated for Plot Interpretation?

Tags: r

Totally new to R, so sorry if the question is phrased poorly or super basic, but  I'm not really understanding any of the guides I can find on my own.

I am trying to run a Principle Coordinate Analysis (PCO) on a dataset I have.  This dataset includes non-numerical information like taxon and age, as well as numerical data.

I want to run a PCO of the numerical data, but keep the non-numerical data associated so that I can color-code/label specimens by those categories in the resulting plot.

Currently, I'm loading the data with `read.table()`, putting it into a matrix with `dist()`, running the pco on the matrix with `pco()` (synonymous with `cmdscale()`), and plotting the pco with `plot()`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much higher chance for getting an answer if you provide some data to play with. Here's some:

```
data(iris)

pca = prcomp(iris[,-5])
```

with gg plot: combine the pca coordinates with the category columns

```
pca_ploting=data.frame(pca$x, Species = iris[,5])

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=pca_ploting)+
  geom_point(aes(x = PC1, y=PC2, color= Species))+
  stat_ellipse(aes(x = PC1, y=PC2, color= Species))
   # an approach I like is to scale the coords by the variance explained
      coord_fixed(ratio = pca$sdev[2]^2/pca$sdev[1]^2)
   # here it does not look so nice because PC1 explains over 90%, while PC2 only about 5%
```

with ggord:

```
library(ggord)
ggord(pca, axes = c("1", "2"), iris[,5], xlims = NULL,
      ylims = NULL, ext = 1.1, vec_ext = 2, size = 1)
```